# Visual Studio:-Unity already has a dependency defined for CommonServiceLocator (VS 2012 Ultimate)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install a package through nuget it shows me installing first successfully and than after some it will rollback and shows a error as installation failed and Unity already has a dependency defined for CommonServiceLocator (VS 2012 Ultimate). I have shown my error below.I have tried the same using nuget package manager but its shows the same error in that as well
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading the version of NuGet that is installed in Visual Studio to the latest version.

The error `'PackageA' already has a dependency defined for 'PackageB'` can happen if PackageA defines a group dependency on a target framework that NuGet does not recognise. This can happen if the version of NuGet is too old to recognise the target framework or is ignoring the target framework defined for the dependency.

```
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="Windows8.0">
    <dependency id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.2.0" />
  </group>
  <group targetFramework="MonoAndroid0.0">
    <dependency id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.2.0" />
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by installing the latest NuGet Package Manager:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca

Make sure restart Visual Studio Instance to get this work.